# How could I find something in an array that I know only parts of

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have these two values how could I match and see all possible combinations that word could be in the array. For this example how could I find apple in the array?

```
const fruit = ["apple", "banana", "strawberry", "grape"];
var word = "a__ple"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Regex` to match partial strings -

```js
const fruit = ["apple", "banana", "strawberry", "grape"];
var regex = "^a.ple$";

var result = fruit.filter(f => f.match(regex));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex from your `word` and then using `array#filter` look up in the array.

```js
const fruit = ["apple", "banana", "strawberry", "grape"],
      word = "a__ple",
      pattern = word.split("_").filter(Boolean).join('(.*?)'),
      result = fruit.filter(name => new RegExp(pattern, 'i').test(name));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Example for solution

```js
fruit = ["apple", "banana", "strawberry", "grape"];
var word = "a_ple";


const searchQuery = word.replace(/[_]/g, '.');
const regex = new RegExp(searchQuery);

for (let i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
    if (regex.test(fruit[i])) {
        // Word is founded
        console.log(fruit[i]);
    }

}
```

but it must use the "_" sign as same as the count of missing characters

also, you can use an index with words instead of search about strings I will try to do another example for this way thanks and I hope this helps you